# phpunit test Class 'Phar' not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phar

Trying to run a phpunit test, but when I run the test...

```
phpunit MyTest.php
```

...I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phar' not found in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 611
```

The php manual says [Phar is installed by default as of `PHP 5.3.0`](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php); I'm using `PHP 5.3.17`. How can I troubleshoot this error?

---

Edit

```
php -i | grep Phar
```

returns nothing.

Comment: check if Phar extension is installed in the CLI version of PHP: `php -i | grep Phar`

Comment: @gontrollez that command returned nothing for me. That doesn't make sense, as the manual says `Phar` is installed by default and offers no further explanation as to how to install it... Can you direct me anywhere to install `Phar`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `phar` `php5 extension module`.

In the cli type:

```
sudo yast //I'm using OpenSUSE, use whatever package manager your OS requires
```

Then software management, search for 'phar' and it was the only option that showed up for me. You should be able to see `Phar` listed in your php information now:

```
php -i | grep Phar

Phar
Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar EXT version => 2.0.1
Phar API version => 1.1.1
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
```

Comment: Your answer applies only to Suse linux I think. That is too specific. At least state it so people won't get confused

Comment: @gontrollez True. Updated.